# django rest_framework when creating object says get() returned more than one Request -- it returned 2

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a api where everytime someone request for repairs it also saves in inspection table

when I try to post in postman

```
{
"reqdescription": "test",
"techofficeid": "ICT"
}
```

this is the row of request

```
|reqid|reqdescription|reqdate|officerequestor|techofficeid|
| 36  | test         |2022...|    HR         |     ICT    |
```

while this is the row of inspection

```
|inspectid|reqid| etc...|    description    |
| 5       | 36  |.......|Request object (36)|
```

instead of test why it's `Request object (36)`

this is my signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Request)
def create_transaction_log(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
  Inspection.objects.create(reqid=Request.objects.get(reqid=instance.reqid),
    description=Request.objects.get(reqdescription=instance.reqdescription),
    reqdate=str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

my assumptions is because of OneToOneField but maybe I was wrong

Hope someone can help

models.py

```
class Inspection(models.Model):
inspectid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
reqid = models.OneToOneField('Request', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='reqid', blank=True, null=True)
insdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
inspector = models.ForeignKey('Technician', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='inspector', blank=True, null=True)
isinspected = models.BooleanField(default='False', blank=True, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
reqdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'inspection'

class Request(models.Model):
reqid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
reqdescription = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
reqdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True, null=True)
officerequestor = models.ForeignKey('Office', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='officerequestor', blank=True, null=True)
techofficeid = models.ForeignKey('Technicianoffice', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='techofficeid', blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'request'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `create_transaction_log` signal you already have the Request object in `instance` parameter. So, you don't need to do `Request.objects.get...` there. Instead, use `instance`, like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Request)
def create_transaction_log(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
  Inspection.objects.create(
    reqid=instance,
    description=instance.reqdescription,
    reqdate=instance.reqdate,
  )
```

BTW, I would not choose `Request` name for the model, to avoid associations with HTTP request.

Comment: ok noted i'll change request model but it's throwing an error ValueError: Cannot assign "52": "Inspection.reqid" must be a "Request" instance.

Comment: I just use Inspection.objects.create(reqid=Request.objects.get(reqid=instance.reqid) and it's working, I just dont know if this is a good practice or not

Comment: oh, right - `reqid` is a `OneToOneField`, so yes, it requires an instance of `Request` model. Then you can do `reqid=instance`. I updated the answer.